# Generating a CSV file in bash when data contains commas

Tags: bash

I am having trouble with a script I wrote in bash. I am reading in a .txt file line by line in a while loop. The line is in the form of x:y:z:a:b:c. Each element ('x', 'a', etc.) corresponds to something such as age, height, name, and so on. I have successfully managed to print out the desired fields, but when I try to print the whole "x:y:z:a:b:c" "x:y:z" will print out to a .csv in one cell, and "a:b:c" will go to the next cell, due to the fact that there is a comma in the last name and first name. I know this sounds confusing so I can clarify further if necessary but here is what it looks like:

```
Cell 1                          Cell 2
age:height:number:last name     first name:language
```

I want all this information in one cell. I think the problem is due to the fact that there is a comma between the last and first name. Please let me know if you have any tips or pointers.

Edit: Here is what the code looks like:

```
while read INPUT do
    str=$INPUT
    IFS=: read -r -a ARR <<< "$str"
    NAME=${ARR[0]}
    AGE=${ARR[3]}
    echo $AGE, $NAME >>Filedirectory.filename.csv
done<filedirectory.filename.txt
```

...where `filedirectory.filename.txt` contains the following:

```
INPUT=Smith, John:126 lbs:67in:26:College University
```

Taking a sample input of `str = "Smith, John:126 lbs:67in:26:College University"`
So, `NAME = Smith, John, AGE = 26. Ideally the output should be 2 cells next to each other populated as:

```
26 - Smith, John
```

Instead the output in excel when I open the CSV file ends up being:

```
12 - Smith - John
```

Where each '-' symbolizes a column (`12` is in one cell, last name in the next, etc.) What I want is for Last Name and First Name to be in one cell, but apparently this is not happening due to the fact that the Name is formatted as "Smith, John" and the comma is messing things up

Comment: Change the delimiter character and open the spreadsheet with the delimiter set to that character?

Comment: Post your code?

Comment: I cannot post my code unfortunately

Comment: You don't need to post your **original** code. What we want is a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code someone else can run (ie. not dependent on your local environment) that replicates the problem.

Comment: Anyhow, bash only splits on commas if you have a comma in `IFS`. If you don't have the comma defined as a field separator, it won't have any effect. And, as general advice, make sure you're following [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) practices for reading content line-by-line. We'd need a reproducer for your problem to provide much beyond such general advice.

Comment: (BTW, it's not clear what the word "cell" means in this context; if we had code, actual output, and intended output all provided in the question, there'd be no need for guesswork).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've added some code, please let me know if that helps

Comment: That's helpful, yes. How about sample input, intended output, and actual output?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've included a sample input just now below my code

Comment: So, your actual problem has nothing whatsoever to do with **echo** splitting on commas, and everything to do with **Excel** splitting on commas.

Comment: BTW -- see http://shellcheck.net/ for automated advice on common errors (like failing to quote expansions; a space-separated `*` in your input will be replaced with a list of filenames in your output if there aren't double quotes around the variable containing it at expansion time). You might also consider following [POSIX-specified convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) re: using lowercase names for your own variables (as uppercase names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell).

Comment: Any way to change the statement in echo to avoid Excel from making this error? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: I've already added my answer *as an answer*.

Comment: When you replace `while read INPUT do` with `while read INPUT; do` the output  will have age 26, not 12.

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation might look like:

```
while IFS=: read -r name _ age _; do
    printf '"%s","%s"\n' "${name//\"/\"\"}" "${age//\"/\"\"}"
done <in.txt >out.csv
```

[Less correctly](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) (see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the linked specification describing caveats), you could do this with `echo`:

```
while IFS=: read -r name _ age _; do
    echo '"'"${name//\"/\"\"}"'","'"${age//\"/\"\"}"'"'
done <in.txt >out.csv
```

---

In both cases, we're surrounding the cell contents with quotes, and using a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to double-up any quotes found inside of the strings, which makes those quotes literal in CSV syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Excel feature:
When the first line is `SEP=:`, the csv file will be read using this as SEP.
Now it is easy:

```
sed -r ' s/([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):.*/\4:\1/;
        1s/.*/SEP=:\n&/'    < filedirectory.filename.txt > outputfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I have found to do this is to is to use a CSV-aware tool, such as [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/), which provides the command `csvformat`:

```sh
while IFS=: read -r name _ age _; do 
    echo -e "${name}\t${age}"; 
done < filedirectory.filename.txt | csvformat -t > outputfile.csv
```